# upower wants to uninstall lots of packages

Tags: installation, upgrade

I'm running Natty and have a problem with upower.

Currently installed is upower 0.9.5-4 (Maverick?), with upower 0.9.9-4 available. Update Manager won't upgrade it, but if I go to Synaptic and use Ctrl+E (force version) it prompts to remove all of the following packages:

> gdm gdm-guest-session gnome-power-manager gnome-session gnome-session-bin indicator-session nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop

This seems like a fair chunk of the GUI, so I'm not keen to let it go ahead. Is there a better/safer way to force the package upgrade?

NOTE: This machine was upgraded from Maverick to Natty using the Alternate CD a while ago. It locked-up about 80-90% through the upgrade requiring the machine to be hard reset, but it finished the upgrade process after rebooting. I was making sure everything was OK before going to Oneiric when I discovered this little gem.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this issue. I downloaded the package manually and installed it with dpkg, which shed some light on the problem that neither Update Manager nor Synaptic alluded to...

Downloading from the [upower 0.9.9-4 (i386 binary) in ubuntu natty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/upower/0.9.9-4) page:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69387943/upower_0.9.9-4_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --no-force-all --install upower_0.9.9-4_i386.deb
```

dpkg gave me the following error output which contained the missing link:

```
(Reading database ... 525265 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace upower 0.9.5-4 (using upower_0.9.9-4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement upower ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upower:
 upower depends on libimobiledevice2 (>= 0.9.7); however:
  Package libimobiledevice2 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing upower (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 upower
```

This time, opening Synaptic (which gave me a broken package warning) I installed libimobiledevice2 which fixed upower and now everything seems to be up to date and working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Natty upgrade did not complete so you're got a broken system that is part Maverick, part Natty.  You might try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and see if it can finish upgrading to Natty.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, psusi, but I managed to get it working as per my own answer below.